# What is the easiest way to use DAO Engine (Access) in Python for a complete application?

Tags: python, windows, ms-access, dao

I am writing a complete application intended to be compiled to .exe (via Py2EXE). I would love to use the DAO object for working with an Access database. I would like to have as little dependencies as possible (for the user - no office install, etc).
Most of the sources I have reviewed claim that the bitness of the Engine/Driver/Office Installation, must all align. This confuses me as to what the user will require on their machine if i compile my working code.

Will they just need Access Run-time for the bitness of the engine I develop the app in?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend Acess with Python.
Python and Access are two completely different "worlds", Python does have the necessary drivers to "speak" to Access but is not a good match especially when it has built in support for SQLite and i reckon far better support for other Database engines.
I am an Access expert and i do Python but i wouldn't mix them unless its for convenience like using the report engine of Access.